# time and space complexity of this insert method

Tags: c++, algorithm

Say I want to insert an item into a sorted stack s. I create a temporary stack s2. I keep pushing them into s2 and popping them from s1 until I reached the position I want to insert at. Then I push it to s. Then I push everything in s2 back into s. Assuming size of s is n, what's the time complexity of this operation? I'm pretty sure it's O(n). Because you pop out at most n elements in s, and pop back at most n items in s2. That gives you O(n) + O(n) which is O(n). Is that right?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

void insert(int item, stack<int> &s){
    stack<int> temp;

    while(s.top() > item){
        int curr = s.top();
        s.pop();
        temp.push(curr);
    }

    s.push(item);

    while(!temp.empty()){
        int curr = temp.top();
        s.push(curr);
        temp.pop();
    }
}

int main(){
    int numbers[] = {1,2,4,5,6};
    stack<int> s;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i+=1){
        s.push(numbers[i]);
        std::cout << "original s: " << s.top() << std::endl;}

    insert(3, s);

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i+=1){
        std::cout << "new s: " << s.top() << std:: endl;
        s.pop();}
}
```

As you see, this code works exactly as I expected. However, I heard this algorithm (using a temporary stack) has something to do with priority queue. And it's insert function is O(logn) instead of O(n). Could anyone clarify for me what the correct time complexity of insert method shown here?

Also I'd like to know the space complexity of the insert method:

My analysis: you declared a temp stack which can be at most size n. Also inside the while loop you declare a new temp everytime the loop is run. So the space complexity is also O(n). Is this right?

P.S. I m aware that I shouldn't use namespace. This is just for convenience here.

Comment: O(n), of course.

Comment: Nothing to do with priority queue. Your analysis for O(n) is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't know what inserting algorithm you are talking about. However, [inserting](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/push/) elements into a priority queue has the complexity of **O(Log N)**. In this case of course your elements are going to be sorted either in descending order (which is the default behavior), or using your own provided comparing function. The final result would be close enough to your code; since you too keep your elements sorted.

To answer your question, yes of course the complexity of your code is **O(N)**.

Answer (score 1):

You algorithm works with `O(n)` and insertion can't be achieved on array or stack with `O(logN)`complexity and the worst case is always `O(N)`. Also, sorted array insertion is slower than for an unsorted array. The reason being that the order of the elements change when we insert and its needs to be corrected. The same goes for stack, unless you don't wish to preserve order after insertion.